# Activating Golos during another player’s turn

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

[Golos, Tireless Pilgrim](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGolos%2c%20Tireless%20Pilgrim%5d)'s ability can be activated during another players turn, but does doing so allow you to still play the cards if it is not your turn? The ability text says you may play those cards “this turn”.

I am assuming that you would not be able to play anything other than any revealed instants unless the revealed card has “flash” or some other card gives those revealed cards flash (e.g. Teferi or Leyline of Anticipation).  Is that correct?

Similarly, because it is not my turn, is playing a revealed land card from Golos forbidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All normal casting restrictions apply for cards exiled with Golos during another player's turn.**

You may play instants and cards with flash. You may not play lands. The phrase "You may play them this turn" only lifts the restriction that you can normally only play cards from your hand.

Answer (score 4):

[Gatherer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=466980) often answers rules questions about cards with special effects directly. In this case, it says

> Golos’s last ability doesn’t change when you can play the exiled cards. For example, if you exile a sorcery card, you can cast it only during your main phase when the stack is empty. If you exile a land card, you can play it only during your main phase and only if you have an available land play remaining.

Which is to say, if you activate him on your opponent's turn, you can only cast exiled instants and cards with flash, just as with regular cards from your hand.